# File uploading issue in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, http, file-upload

I am uploading video to server with HTTP posting.

I am using the following code

```
 NSString *urlString =@"http://sampleurl.com/upload_video";

 NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
 [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


  [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user_id\"\r\n\r\n%@", appDelegate.userid] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


   [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", @"a.mov"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   [postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:file]];
   [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   [request setHTTPBody:postbody];

    conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (conn) {
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
     }
```

this is the function I am using to find out the bytes written and total bytes

```
 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(    NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite{



    NSLog(@"------%i------%i-----------",totalBytesWritten ,totalBytesExpectedToWrite);



  NSDictionary *uploadStatus=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",totalBytesWritten],@"bytesWritten",
                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",totalBytesExpectedToWrite],@"totalBytes",
                            nil];

   [uploadStatus release];
      }
```

When my app goes back ground uploading get paused,and when it back in foreground it resumes uploading
**My problem is...if I upload a lengthy video,it takes time and phone got auto locked,after that uploading process is not working,ie uploading get stuck and I am forced to restart the app**

Why it is happening..Please help me to clear this
thanks in advance

Comment: dont let the app go in background while uploading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple introduced multi-tasking support for applications. The multi-tasking support relies on putting apps into a background state, where they can be quickly restored to full interactive mode, but not consume resources while in the background. This can present a problem for network applications such as those built with `RestKit:` important long-running requests can be interrupted by the user switching out of the app. Thankfully Apple also provided limited support for extending the life of your process by creating a background task using the `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` method on `UIApplication`. This method accepts an Objective-C block and returns a `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier` value for the background task that was created. Care must be taken when creating the background task so that backward compatibility with iOS 3.0 deployments is maintained.

See the topic from **Background Upload/Download** from

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/advanced-restkit-development_iphone-sdk/ link.

Also see this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW28

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2277/_index.html

The following line disable sleep time of iOS device.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES]
```